# how to remove all traces of parity on windows

Tags: parity

I previously tried to delete parity from this machine, ans succeeded to an extent.  but there is still something running in the background, taking up memory.  until the thing stops running, it won't let me delete the info.

does the following picture help any with diagnosis?  the memory amounts associated with these folders keep changing, so something is running.  I've tried using task manager, but don't see anything obvious.. thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find the Parity tray icon, right click it and stop Parity.
2. Use task manager to check if Parity is still running, if yes, force stop parity.
3. Uninstall Parity via Start Menu or System Settings.
4. Backup your keys, refer to [FAQ: Backup, Restore, and Files](https://paritytech.github.io/wiki/FAQ-Backup,-Restore,-and-Files.html)
5. Make sure you have redundant backups of your keys.
6. Never lose your keys.
7. Remove the blockchain data in

   ```
   C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Parity
   ```
8. Remove keys and configuration in

   ```
   C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\Parity
   ```
9. Remove installation leftovers in

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Parity
   ```

Et voila! All traces gone.